# При использовании Twig не вставляется блок

Tags: twig

Всем привет. Кажется, я заблудилась в трех соснах, помогите распутаться.
Это указываю в файле homepage:

```html
{% block headerblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

А это в header.twig

```html
{% extends "homepage.twig" %} 

{% block headerblock %}
<header class="header">
  <div class="logo">
    {% for key, i in images %} {% if key in ['114'] %}
    <img src="{{ i.img }}" alt="{{ i.description }} />
    {% endif %} {% endfor %}
  </div>
  <nav>
    <ul class="header__list">
      {% for m in menu %}
      <li class="header__list--item">
        <a
          href="{{ m.href }}"
          title="{{ m.title }}"
          alt="{{ m.alt }}"
          class="header__list--link"
          >{{ m.name }}</a
        >
      </li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
{% endblock %}
```

Хедер на главной не появляется. Что я упустила/сделала не так?

Comment: UPD: хедер появился в конце страницы. Блок стоит до main. Почему так может происходить?

Comment: до какого "main" стоит непонятно.